# Excel formulas for capitalizing the first letter after period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any formula that i can use in Excel to capitalize the first letter after period? I have multiple sentences in one cell and each sentence is separated by period. 
I have tried the `PROPER` FUNCTION as well as the `UPPER` FUNCTION but I don't get the result that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Below formula might work for you:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),". ","9z9")," ","zxz")),"9Z9",". "),"zxz"," ")
```

It basically `SUBSTITUTE`s the periods and blanks with some 3 character strings to trick the `PROPER` code as if each sentence is one word only. And then re `SUBSTITUTE` the strings with periods and blanks.

[The source](https://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/07/convert-to-sentence-case-excel-formula/).

EDIT: After @chronocidal 's warning, I have realized that the formula cannot handle already existing uppercase characters since it basically lowercase everything at the very beginning. So it seems that we need a custom formula solution now.

When below code is entered to a **module** in the Excel file. We will be able to use the custom formula `sCase` to achieve what we need. Credits goes to [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/convert-text-sentence-ca-t1128348.html) for this solution.

```
Public Function sCase(ByRef strIn As String) As String
Dim bArr() As Byte, i As Long, i2 As Long
If strIn = vbNullString Then Exit Function
Let bArr = strIn
Select Case bArr(0)
    Case 97 To 122
        bArr(0) = bArr(0) - 32
End Select
For i = 2 To UBound(bArr) Step 2
    Select Case bArr(i)
        Case 105
            If Not i = UBound(bArr) - 1 Then
                Select Case bArr(i + 2)
                    Case 32, 33, 39, 44, 46, 58, 59, 63, 148, 160
                        If bArr(i - 2) = 32 Then _
                            bArr(i) = bArr(i) - 32
                End Select
            ElseIf bArr(i - 2) = 32 Then _
                bArr(i) = bArr(i) - 32
            End If
        Case 33, 46, 58, 63
            For i2 = i + 2 To UBound(bArr) Step 2
                Select Case bArr(i2)
                    Case 97 To 122
                        bArr(i2) = bArr(i2) - 32
                        i = i2:   Exit For
                End Select
                Select Case bArr(i2)
                    Case 32, 33, 46, 63, 160
                    Case Else
                        i = i2:   Exit For
                End Select
            Next
    End Select
Next
sCase = bArr
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm...  An interesting start, but it won't work with Proper Nouns:  i.e. if your input is "hello.  my name is Ronald McDonald.  what is yours?" then you get "Hello.  My name is ronald mcdonald.  What is yours?" as output

Comment: You are right, I have failed to see that scenario, thanks for warning. I have edited the answer with a custom formula solution. If the OP finds the solution useless since the original request seems to be a pure formula, I will delete the answer.